# AngularJS 2 influenced by URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I'm using AngularJS 2 in a ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I do not use the routing provided by Angular and rely only on the MVC routing strategy.

Strangely, AngularJS seems to look at the URL and only load correctly when I'm on a route **"domain/Controller"**, if I'm on a route as **"domain/Controller/"** or **"domain/Controller/Action"** my Angular app is not loading and I have the following error in the browser:

[image]

I'm using the following script to load my bootstrapper:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('../tsScripts/boot').catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

**my boot.ts file:**

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent} from './app';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

I have no idea why Angular (or another part coming with the framework) is incompatible with the MVC routing, or what is wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Angular2 is a Single Page Application framework so not using its router kind of defeats the whole idea. Looks like you have issues with SystemJs config.

Comment: I'd suspect it's in the SystemJS configuration file as well. You may need to post the contents. It defines where to download files from. The base paths would need to be updated based on the current route. (But as mentioned by @rook, it's unlikely that you should do that given that Angular 2 isn't intended to be loaded over and over as a user navigates ).

Comment: Here is my SystemJs config http://pastebin.com/2JyvhcNK
I'm interested by AngularJs for its MV* functionalities, but I would like to keep the navigation/routing/authentication policies from ASP.NET MVC. But it seems it's not the good tool for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, 
and I simply solved it placing this code into the **head** tag of **_Layout.cshtml** (so that is applied to all views)

```html
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

[Angular official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-lt-base-href-)

---

You can also fix it this way

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [RouterModule], 
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
]);
```